# Fetching the username who last modified or created the file

Tags: c#, fileinfo

Is it possible to get the name of the user who just pasted a file into a folder?

A brief overview of what I am trying to do:
My application keeps watch on a folder for new files every 10 minutes. If it finds any new file it will upload that file via FTP to a specified location.
I would like to know who dropped this file into the folder. Please note that this could be different from the person who created the file.

Thanks
 Nishant

Comment: What filesystem is on the FTP server? Does it have such support?

Answer (score 0):

The identity of the user modifying a file is not stored in the [NTFS Change Journal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363803(v=vs.85).aspx), but you could use auditing of file access as suggested in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290694/how-do-you-monitor-file-access-and-changes-on-a-file-server-by-user-name).