# How to get username from a file dropped in a shared folder monitored by FileSystemWatcher in a windows service

Tags: c#, windows, filesystemwatcher

I want to get the usernames of windows users dropping files in a shared network folder. The folder is monitored by a FileSystemWatcher/windowsservice.
Is that possible?

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9188961/891715

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/425625/how-to-find-windows-7-file-transfer-history

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, the file system has already lost this information by the time the event is raised, the only possible solution is to build a custom driver that loads into the kernel to remember the information and get your application to read from it.

Here is some more information on [File System Filter Drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/ifs/introduction-to-file-system-filter-drivers)