# .NET How to combine FileSystemWatcher with ReadDirectoryChangesW to monitor Folder/File Opening?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, readdirectorychangesw

I am currently using FileSystemWatcher to monitor my local file system changes but i want to monitor Folder/File opening. after a lot of investigations, i found that this can be done using ReadDirectoryChangesW but i can't use this method along with FileSystemWatcher. My question is how to combine ReadDirectoryChangesW  with FileSystemWatcher with a sample code on how to do this.

```
public class Watcher : FileSystemWatcher
{

}
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense, FileSystemWatcher **is** a .NET wrapper for ReadDirectoryChangesW().  It does everything that the api function does.

Comment: *but i want to monitor Folder/File opening. after a lot of investigations, i found that this can be done* Some reference on this? I see on MSDN That someone in 2013 asked for a `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILEOPENSTATE`, but it seems it was a feature request.

Comment: Hi Xanatos, Do you mean no solution exist for this issue? or the feature isn't implemented yet?

Comment: @yo2011 I mean "I don't know. I'm curious". You said that you've found, so it means that there is some documentation about it. I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

To get events like accessed - you need to add an audit on this directory/files.
Then you can consume audit entries to see who/when accessed file
see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290694/how-do-you-monitor-file-access-and-changes-on-a-file-server-by-user-name)